# How to design collapsible list with in reactjs component with plus minus toggle along with the title text

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have created a react component for sidebar menu. I do not want to use bootstrap accordian for the purpose. I want to create a menu list with plus minus sign toggle. In the code below, if list items under Technical analysis are open it should show "Technical Analysis -". How can I achieve similar list as pic attached?[image]

```
import React, {Fragment, useState} from "react";
import {Col, Collapse, Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Row} from "react-bootstrap";
import {Link, useRouteMatch} from "react-router-dom";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";

const SidebarL = () => {

const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const [open1, setOpen1] = useState(false);
const [open2, setOpen2] = useState(false);
let {url} = useRouteMatch();


return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <div onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                 aria-controls="collapse-text"
                 aria-expanded={open}
            >
              <Link style={{textDecoration: "none", color: "black"}}>
                <div>
                  Technical Analysis
                </div>
              </Link>
            </div>
            <Collapse in={open}>
                <div id="collapse-text">
                    <ul className="list-unstyled border-left p-2 ml-2">
                        <li>
                          <Link to={`${url}/thedowtheory`}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
                          >
                            The Dow Theory
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to={`${url}/charts`}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>
                            Chart & Chart Patterns
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to={`${url}/trendlines`}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>
                            Trend & Trend Lines
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to={`${url}/supportresistance`}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>
                            Support & Resistance
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </Collapse>
            <hr className="mt-2 mb-2" />
            <div onClick={() => setOpen1(!open1)}
                 aria-controls="collapse-text1"
                 aria-expanded={open1}
            >
                <Link style={{textDecoration: "none", color: "black"}}>
                  <div>Fundamental Analysis </div>
                </Link>
            </div>
            <Collapse in={open1}>
                <div id="collapse-text1" >
                    <ul className="list-unstyled border-left p-2 ml-2"
                    >
                        <li>
                          <Link to={`${url}/supportresistance`}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
                          >
                            Link
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to={`${url}/supportresistance`}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
                          >
                            Link
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to={`${url}/supportresistance`}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
                          >
                            Link
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to={`${url}/supportresistance`}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
                          >
                            Link
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </Collapse>
            <hr className="mt-2 mb-2" />
            <div onClick={() => setOpen2(!open2)}
                 aria-controls="collapse-text2"
                 aria-expanded={open2}
            >
              <Link style={{textDecoration: "none", color: "black"}}>
                  Elliot Wave Analysis
              </Link>
            </div>
            <Collapse in={open2}>
                <div id="collapse-text2" >
                    <ul className="list-unstyled border-left p-2 ml-2"
                    >
                        <li>
                          <Link to={`${url}/supportresistance`}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
                          >
                            Link
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to={`${url}/supportresistance`}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
                          >
                            Link
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to={`${url}/supportresistance`}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
                          >
                            Link
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to={`${url}/supportresistance`}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
                          >
                            Link
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </Collapse>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={7} className="border-left">
          Content
        </Col>
        <Col className="border-left">
          SidebarR
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
)


}

   export default SidebarL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes you're asking about the mechanics of such a menu and not the specifics of the styling.

For the accordion, create a configuration object that represents the menu items. There are many ways you could do this, but here's an example tree structure that would accommodate a submenus of any depth:

```js
const menu = [
  {
    title: 'Getting Started with Technical Analysis',
    items: [
      {
        title: 'Best ways to learn technical analysis',
        href: `${url}/best-ways-to-learn`,
      },
      {
        title: 'Top 7 Books',
        href: `${url}/top-7-books`,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Essential Technical Analysis Strategies',
    items: [
      {
        title: 'Intro to Strategies',
        href: `${url}/intro-to-strategies`,
      }
    ],
  }
];
```

With this structure in place you can create a recursive menu item component that renders an entry's title and its children:

```
const MenuItem = ({ item: { title, items = [], href } }) => (
  <li>
    <div className='menu-item-title'>{title}</div>
    
    { items.length && (
      <ul className='submenu'>
        { items.map( item => <MenuItem key={item.title} item={item} /> ) }
      </ul>
    )}
  </li>
)
```

With that in place you can add a bit of component state and css to expand/collapse the submenus:

```
// adding expanded/collapsed state to MenuItem component from before
const MenuItem = ({ item: { title, items = [], href } }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);
  const clickHandler = React.useCallback(() => setExpanded(!expanded), [expanded]);

  return (
    <li onClick={clickHandler} className={expanded ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'}>
      <div className='menu-item-title'>{title}</div>
        { items.length && (
          <ul className='submenu'>
            { items.map( item => <MenuItem key={item.title} item={item} /> }
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}
```

You can control the rest with CSS.

```css
.collapsed .submenu {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you only want one item expanded at a time you could pass an onChange handler from the top that could collapse other items when something is expanded.

Comment: Hey Ray, thanks for this very helpful guidance. I have collapsible menu already in place. I want to add plus minus sign with menu title which changes with change in menu state.

Comment: with your code, I am getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Comment: You have to pass a valid `item` prop to MenuItem.

Comment: The plus/minus can be hung off of the `expanded` state.

Comment: Hey Ray, I am not able to get rid of above error, can you please help me?

Comment: Sure. Do you have a specific question? I can try to turn the example above into a working demo but I can't do it right now. Maybe later today.

Comment: There were a couple typos in my examples above. Updated to correct.

Comment: I threw together a [working demo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hierarchical-menu-demo-v1c1j?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63193406/13558699, all the items are getting expanded or collapsed together