# Toggle sidebar menu with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am currently working on a react project for learning. My aim is to design a sidebar with toggle menu. I am halfway on it with the help from many of you and have designed it, but getting a small problem. If I click on the list to toggle the menu items, instead of single item, all items expand at once. I am unable to resolve it with my current configuration. Please help me, my code is as below,

```
import React, {useCallback, useState} from "react";
import {List} from "@material-ui/core";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import {Link, useRouteMatch} from "react-router-dom";
import {Container, Row, Col, Collapse} from "react-bootstrap";
import '../Home/myStyle.css'
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";



let {url} = useRouteMatch;
export const menu = [
  {
    label: 'Technical Analysis',
    items: [
      {
        title: 'The Dow Theory',
        href: `${url}/thedowtheory`
      },
      {
        title: 'Charts & Chart Patterns',
        href: `${url}/charts`
      },
      {
        title: 'Trends & Trendlines',
        href: `${url}/trends`
      },
      {
        title: 'Support & Resistance',
        href: `${url}/support`
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Fundamental Analysis',
    items: [
      {
        title: 'Link',
        href: `${url}/thedowtheory`
      },
      {
        title: 'Link',
        href: `${url}/charts`
      },
      {
        title: 'Link',
        href: `${url}/trends`
      },
      {
        title: 'Link',
        href: `${url}/support`
      }
    ]
  }
]


export const Sidebar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const clickHandler = useCallback(
    () => setOpen(open => !open),
    [setOpen]
  );

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          {menu.map((item, index) =>
            <ul key={index}
                className="p-0"
            >
              <div onClick={clickHandler}
                   aria-controls={`menu${index}`}
                   aria-expanded={open}
              >
                <Link style={{textDecoration: "none", color: "black"}}>
                  {open ? '-' + ' ' + item.label : '+' + ' ' + item.label}
                </Link>
                {item.items.map((item, index) =>
                  <Collapse in={open}>
                    <div id={`menu${index}`}>
                      <ul className="list-unstyled border-left p-1 pl-3">
                        <li>
                          <Link key={index}
                                to={item.href}
                                style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
                          >
                            {item.title}
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </Collapse>
                )}
              </div>
              <hr/>
            </ul>
          )}
        </Col>

        <Col xs={7} className="border-left">Content</Col>
        <Col className="border-left">Sidebar</Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Also, how to add plus/minus icons

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve.

When you click on an item, you are setting a generic **open** state, so when you render, you don't know which item exactly is open.

What I would do is instead of having a boolean flag for the open state, I would put an id | null type. The initial state would be null (no items are expanded) and on each click, you would set the state to an identifier of the page.

When you are rendering, instead of checking if open is true, you will check if open is equal to the current item in the loop that you are doing.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(null);

const handleClick = (itemId) => () => setOpen(itemId);

return items.map(item => (
   <div className={open === item.id ? "active" : ""} onClick={handleClick(item.id)}>
      {item.label}
   </div>
);
```

The above code won't compile, but it should be able to guide you.

Comment: I am not able to apply it in my above code, can you please guide?

Comment: here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-zhukovsky-5x9d9?file=/src/Sidebar.js